# Cannot call the include method in Entity framework 7

Tags: include, entity-framework-core

Using EF7 beta 5 and can not call the include method like:

```
var blogs=context.Blogs.Include(x=>x.Posts).ToList();
```

Did I miss something or is it maybe not jet implemented.

Comment: Found a way to do it (e.g. in RC2)?

Answer (score 4):

Actually the answer is quite obvious :-)
You need to add a using to the top of your source code file:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity
```

Comment: So how then to get nested object out of the DB? Is the only way to make nested queries?